# jQuery get class of selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of divs that are buttons on my site. When I click a button I want a sub nav to show. All the sub navs have the class of "subNab" but also have a class the same as the main nav appended with "Sub". For example I have:

```
<div class="navBox audits">
    <p>Audits</p>
</div>

<div class="subNav auditsSub">
    <div class="navBox">
        <p>Audits Sub1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navBox">
        <p>Audits Sub2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I have the sub nav hiding on page load and showing on a click function, along with hiding the subNav again so they don't just stack up. I have the below code with the different class names for each button. There's got to be an easier way.

```
    $(".audits").click(function(){
        $(".subNav").hide();
        $(".auditsSub").fadeIn("slow"); 
        $("#adSlider").hide();
    });
    $(".billing").click(function(){
        $(".subNav").hide();
        $(".billingSub").fadeIn("slow"); 
        $("#adSlider").hide();
    });
    $(".consulting").click(function(){
        $(".subNav").hide();
        $(".consultingSub").fadeIn("slow"); 
        $("#adSlider").hide();
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest solution will be to add another attribute like `data-target=".auditsSub"` to the trigger button

Comment: Arun's suggestion is what you should do. Parsing the class name and then appending "Sub" is quite possible but it becomes a mess. When you read the classes from an element, you get all of them. Then you have to figure out which you want before appending it. Not very clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give me the full code so I can see exactly how you want to handle your menu. If you organize your code correctly you don't have to give each trigger button a class.
Maybe this is what you are looking for:
$(document).ready( function() {

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.submenu').hide();
$('.menu ul li a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents link from redirrecting
    $('.submenu').hide(); // hide all submenu items
    $(this).siblings('.submenu').slideDown (); // show only child submenu
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/75d67hLq/1/